# Can't add normal Comment section in my Django web-application

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have trouble with adding comments to my django web-application. I want to add comments to allow users comment posts, like in normal web blog. I've tried a few ways, but nothing worked correctly for me.

After a few weeks searching and trying different ways to solve this question, I've stacked on this question. I have some progress, but it's now what I want completely.

Now I can only add "comments" from admin panel

[image]

and it look like this (from admin panel)

[image]

and like this (from user interface)

[image]

And I have this issue with padding comments( I don't really understand why it's occurs ¯_(ツ)_/¯ )

Anyway, here is my code, hope someone know how to solve this problem:

*models.py*

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

...

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', default="images/None/no-img.jpg")
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=500, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

*post_detail.html*

```
<article class="media content-section">
  {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
   <ul>
    {{ comment.text }}
    {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        <li>
            {{ reply.text }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
   <ul>
   {% endfor %}
</article>
```

I also read [this article](https://realpython.com/get-started-with-django-1/#share-your-knowledge-with-a-blog) about creation blog for beginners, and they have working comment section as I want, but I tried to implement their code to my web-app, and nothing worked for me.

They have comment section like this (I need completely the same one):
[image]

But when I tried to follow their tutorial, I have only like this:

[image]

And here is the code for this unsuccessful solution( but I feel like it is working one, maybe I did something wrong)

*post_detail.html*

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <article class="media content-section">
    <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" alt="">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2 author_title" href="{% url 'user-posts' object.author.username %}">@{{ object.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"N d, Y" }}</small>

      <div>
        <!-- category section -->
        <small class="text-muted">
          Categories:&nbsp;
          {% for category in post.categories.all %}
          <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
            {{ category.name }}
          </a>&nbsp;
          {% endfor %}
        </small>
      </div>

      {% if object.author == user %}
        <div>
          <a class='btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-update' object.slug %}">Update</a>
          <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1' href="{% url 'post-delete' object.slug %}">Delete</a>
        </div>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
      <img class="img-fluid center" id="rcorners3" src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="none">
      <h2 class="article-title text-center">{{ object.title }}</h2>
      <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
  </article>
<article class="media content-section">
  <form action="/blog/{{ post.pk }}/" method="post">

       {% csrf_token %}

       <div class="form-group">

           {{ form.author }}

       </div>

       <div class="form-group">

           {{ form.body }}

       </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

   </form>

   <h3>Comments:</h3>

   {% for comment in comments %}

   <p>

       On {{comment.created_on.date }}&nbsp;

       <b>{{ comment.author }}</b> wrote:

   </p>

   <p>{{ comment.body }}</p>

   <hr>

   {% endfor %}
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

*views.py*

```
...
def comment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = Comment(
                author=form.cleaned_data["author"],
                body=form.cleaned_data["body"],
                post=post
            )
            comment.save()

    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    context = {
        "post": post,
        "comments": comments,
        "form": form,
    }
```

*models.py*

```
...
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    author = forms.CharField(
        max_length=60,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Your Name"
        })
    )
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(
        attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Leave a comment!"
        })
    )
```

Comment: In your comment model, you have text, but in your comment form, you have body. Maybe you can try fix your form first, and try.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I noticed that you also have imagefield in your post. Is it your intention to only allow one image for a post? I can imagine that a post might have several images, and you may also want to allow user to style their posts. If this is the case, you might want to use Django-ckeditor for your text area which allows richtext editing, multiple image upload, emojis and many more.

Comment: @ha-neul Thank you, it's tool I was looking for and can't find :) Now it will be a lot easier for me to make user-friendly post section.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating unnecessary  lists. Try this one

```html
<article class="media content-section">

   <ul>
   {% for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <li>{{ comment.text }}</li>
    {% if comment.replies.all %}
    <ul>
      {% for reply in comment.replies.all %}
        <li>{{ reply.text }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
     </ul>
     {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
   <ul>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks man, had made it by another way. If you're interested, feel free to check my another questions(there is an answer in one of them)